# Invalid XML during serialization

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I attach this code which WORKED until now, like for a year:

```
// prepare serializer (XSContent)
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XSContent));

using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(this.fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
   // prepare the content for xml serialization
   XSContent content = new XSContent();
   content.UserList = XSConverter.ConvertList<XSUser, TBSUser>(input.UserList);
   content.GroupList = XSConverter.ConvertList<XSGroup, TBSGroup>(input.GroupList);

   // perform serialization
   serializer.Serialize(textWriter, content);                
 }
```

But today, the same code I tested with bigger amount of data: the xml result is getting invalid (please note the 'leftovers' at the end of the entire content):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <UserList>
      <User UserID="CI-0123">
          {...}
      </User>
      {...} 
    </UserList>
    <GroupList>
      <Group GroupID="TEST01">
        <GroupName>Test</GroupName>
        <UserList>
          <UserID>CI-0123</UserID>
        </UserList>
      </Group>    
      {...}
    </GroupList>
 </Content>rID>AT-TEST-2348</UserID>
    <UserID>AT-TEST-2349</UserID>
    <UserID>AT-TEST-2350</UserID>
```

This drives me crazy and I am stuck. Where do you think I should look for? What do I do wrong?

Maybe is important to mention that this xml file is ~200Mb. Also, if something is not clear, I could provide more info.

**EDIT1:**
There is no existing file which may interfere. File is created as new in my tests!

**EDIT2:**
If I add a `textWriter.WriteLine("XYZ")` at the end, it appears right after `</Content>`, but I still see the garbage after XYZ (like: `</Content>XYZ>AT-TEST-2348</UserID>`)

**EDIT3:**
Very strange, when I increased the buffer to 8192 it worked fine. After that, I went back to 4096 and continued to work fine. I see this [FileOptions.SequencialScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx) and they write: "correct operation is still quaranteed". Well, I start to think maybe something went wrong with this (?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it seemed to work when using `Truncate` mode (the file was always there in my case, created during app startup).

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
    using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096)) {
      using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
        ...
      }
    }
```

If you check the StreamWriter constructor, it is done like this:

```
[SecurityCritical]
private static Stream CreateFile(string path, bool append, bool checkHost)
{
    FileMode mode = append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create;
    return new FileStream(path, mode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan, Path.GetFileName(path), false, false, checkHost);
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx for enumeration values.

Comment: Interesting thought, I could give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it doesn't help... same behavior... uh ... If I could find which is the default FileOptions value. I have no clue if this is really important, but SequentialScan sounds good

Comment: Can you correct the StreamWriter constructor since the 3rd param is encoding? Btw, how can I see this stuff?

Comment: I don't know which version of .NET FW are you using; but for me the new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8) works; as for where can you see this stuff - download reflector tool (such as ILSpy); it allows you to see .NET internals. Just for clarity sake - the problem is in File.CreateNew vs File.Create; the default StreamWriter constructor if it doesn't get stream reference, creates his own stream with FileMode.Create which doesn't delete the existing file. So the leftovers are from your previous run (at least that is my theory).

Comment: yeah, I realized why you would say that, but I deleted this file myself before. So, I am sure there is no leftover from any existing file

Comment: And the app is single-threaded, and you're running this just once, right ?

Comment: well, I run this operation in a BackgroundWorker, but I am pretty sure only this thread is accessing the file! Thanks... Btw: there is no random behavior, but always the same output!

Comment: Just to rule that out - can you create static variable like this - static object s_SyncRoot = new object(); and enclose your exporting code into statement lock(s_SyncRoot) { /* serialization stuff */ }

Comment: I think I could also put FileShare.None, right? ... same result

Comment: Yes. Can you try little test - before leaving the textWriter context, put there line textWriter.WriteLine("Banan"); is the world Banan at the end of file or right after Content element ?